# Density plot and histogram using java

Tags: java, javascript, statistics

I want to replicate this plot using java or javascript.[image]

This chart (histogram + Density) can be easily created by using seaborn package in python.
But we are struggling to do it in java.

Please suggest which libraries or classes/code i can use to create them.

Comment: What's your target platform? Web page served by java application server? Java desktop application? Swing? JavaFX?

Comment: its a java desktop application

Comment: I'm basically a business analyst with not much knowledge on java, had suggested this chart to the developer and as he is struggling, im trying to find out options for him :-((